# Materialize CSS Carousel show indicators on mouseenter

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

Hello I have a problem.

I am trying to change the options of an Carousel instance on `mouseenter` event. What do I need to do in order to re-render the instance?

My html:

```
  <div class="carousel carousel-slider center">
    <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
      <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">button</a>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item red white-text" href="#one!">
      <h2>First Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your first panel</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item amber white-text" href="#two!">
      <h2>Second Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your second panel</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item green white-text" href="#three!">
      <h2>Third Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item blue white-text" href="#four!">
      <h2>Fourth Panel</h2>
      <p class="white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

My js:

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
    var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, {
          fullWidth: true,
          indicators: false
    });
  });

document.querySelector('.carousel').
    addEventListener('mouseenter', function(event) {
      var elem = document.querySelector('.carousel');
      M.Carousel.getInstance(elem).options.indicators = true;
    });
```

Here is example on codepen: https://codepen.io/bearwithme/pen/MWaOvbX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok first up, I would initialise the indicators to begin with and then just hide and show them with simple css onhover. Waaaaaay easier.

If you ***must*** change the function on mouseenter, you'd need to destroy the instance and re-init:

```
instance.destroy();
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel');
var instances = M.Carousel.init(elems, {
          fullWidth: true,
          indicators: true
    });
```

https://materializecss.com/carousel.html#methods

Comment: Yes, I ended up hiding it with extra classes indeed.

The problem with re-initializing was that it does not destroy the `<div class="indicators">` and I would have to do that with extra js.

I think it would be nice if the component had it as a native feature in next version, seems like a pretty common use-case to me.